# error when using animateWithDuration UIImage switch case

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am trying to set the frame of my image beforehand, and then transform it using `animateWithDuration`.  It works fine until I add my animation code.  The error I am receiving is:

> exc_bad_access(code=2, address=0x0). case 1:

```
       [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-400, -150, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];      
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jennLawrence.JPG"];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:55 
                              delay:0.5
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                             imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 80, 0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;            
                         }];
```

Comment: Try replace `animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                             imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 80, 0);
                         }` by  `animations:^{
                         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 80, 0);
                     }`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That got the image to animate, but seems to be overriding the original [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-400, -150, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];   The image is now starting at a different point when first loaded.

Comment: Is there a way I can set the original position I want for the image inside of the ViewDidLoad method?  Rather than having to set it inside of my switch statement, and then set it again 2 lines later?

Comment: just put `[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-400, -150, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];      
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jennLawrence.JPG"];` in viewDidLoad. What's the problem?

Comment: I have 5 images inside of my switch statement, randomly generated.  so jennLawrence will not be the only one shown.  Do I put your given code for each of the 5 images?

Comment: just `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jennLawrence.JPG"];` in switch. put `[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-400, -150, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];` in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put your completion block statement inside the IF condition of finished parameter.

The finished parameter will be NO when the animation was cancelled: typically, when you have interrupted the animation to start another one (e.g. you have begun a new animation, before the current one has ended, with the parameter to begin from the current state) or you have directly cancelled the animation.

So, even if animation was cancelled your completion block will still be called and that may result into crash.

Crash seems to be happening due to accessing an object which does not exists. You can also try using `Zoombie` to narrow down the object causing the crash.